# WebEssentials 2012 Less CSS files generation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-essentials

I want to organsise my .Less files in a way that means that only the top level one be converted to .CSS

The rest of the .Less files will be imported to a single level file. I realise I could get a similar single file end result with bundling but there are always going to be some files that would still be import only and never used as specific CSS files.

Can I do this with WebEssentials?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with web essentials.  In Tools > Options > Web Essentials > LESS there are some options for compiling and generating css.

If there are some files that you do not want compiled you can prefix them with an underscore and they will be ignored.

e.g.

```
_PatsAwesomeStyles.less
```

[Don't compile nested files](https://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3319359-don-t-compile-nested-less-files)

Comment: I thought there would be an option too but sadly not in the version I am using. WebEssentials 2012.